# Send GET parameter on url_for inside HTML

Tags: python, flask, request, jinja2

I have the following code:

```
<ul>
    {% for name in items %}
        <li style="list-style-type: none;">
            <a href="{{ url_for('content', values='{{name}}') }}">{{ items[name].title }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I want to insert into the `url_for` a GET parameter that will be the name of the item. When I get the value sent to my `views.py`, I get the whole string `'{{name}}'`.

```
@app.route('/content', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def content():
    name = request.args.get('values')
    print name

>> {{name}}
```

I've tried concatenating with `+` like `{{ url_for('content', values='"+{{name}}+"') }}">{{ items[name].title }}`, but it didn't work too.

Any clues on how to do that? Is it possible to send a POST param that way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use the variable `name` directly in the expression:

```
{{ url_for('content', values=name) }}
```

`'{{name}}'` is a literal string with the characters `{`, `{`, `n`, etc, not an interpolation of the variable.

Note that this is *not* a POST parameter; it is a URL query parameter (part of the URL after the `?`).